# How to access the Kubernetes API in Go and run kubectl commands

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to access my Kubernetes cluster API in Go to run `kubectl` command to get available namespaces in my k8s cluster which is running on google cloud.

My sole purpose is to get namespaces available in my cluster by running `kubectl` command: kindly let me know if there is any alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You can start with [`kubernetes/client-go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go), the Go client for Kubernetes, made for talking to a kubernetes cluster. (not through kubectl though: directly through the Kubernetes API)

It includes a [`NamespaceLister`, which helps list Namespaces](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/listers/core/v1/namespace.go#L28-L35).

See "[Building stuff with the Kubernetes API — Using Go](https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-part-4-using-go-b1d0e3c1c899)" from **[Vladimir Vivien](https://twitter.com/VladimirVivien)**

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*4noxYkVSvMPmlbt1kSOIHw.png]

[Michael Hausenblas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396567/michael-hausenblas) (Developer Advocate at Red Hat) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325091/how-to-access-the-kubernetes-api-in-go-and-run-kubectl-commands#comment91597517_52325186) documentations with [`using-client-go.cloudnative.sh`](http://using-client-go.cloudnative.sh/)

> A versioned collection of snippets showing how to use `client-go`.

Comment: To be clear, client-go doesn't run kubectl under the hood, it talks directly to the API which is much faster and better :)

Comment: Yeah, what coderanger said (and maybe VonC wants to update his answer?). Also, I've started to gather docs at http://using-client-go.cloudnative.sh (early days, WIP) and if there are any questions, hop on the #client-go-docs channel on the Kubernetes Slack community.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Thank you. I have edited the answer and included your comment for more visibility.

Comment: Thank you very much VonC for your response. I find this link very helpful but I am unable to get go-client. I am using this command to get go-client but I don't get any response. "go get k8s.io/client-go/..." I am using VS Code as an IDE. Thank you.

Comment: @MSA Try first in command-line: check also https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/INSTALL.md